# PostgreSQL delete with inner join

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
DELETE B.* 
FROM   m_productprice B  
       INNER JOIN m_product C ON B.m_product_id = C.m_product_id 
WHERE  C.upc = '7094' AND B.m_pricelist_version_id = '1000020'
```

i am getting the following error PostgreSQL 8.2.11

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "B"
LINE 1: DELETE B.* from m_productprice B  INNER JOIN m_product C ON ...
```

i tried giving

```
DELETE B from m_productprice B  INNER JOIN m_product C ON B....
 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "B"
```

i tried giving

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER"
LINE 1: DELETE from m_productprice B  INNER JOIN m_product C ON B.m_...
```

what is the problem with my query?

Comment: 8.2? You should upgrade as soon as possible. That version is no longer supported. And please read the manual: there is no `INNER JOIN` available for the DELETE statement: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-delete.html

Comment: any alternate method for executing this query without inner join

Comment: See the manual, there is an example for exactly that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name In the current 8.2 documentation it does not explicitly state that you cannot use a `JOIN` with `DELETE`. It suggests using their alternative non-standard `USING` syntax and otherwise suggests a `WHERE` but it does not mention anywhere that `JOIN` is not supported. Given that JOINs in DELETE clauses are allowed in MySQL and SQL Server, Postgres is the odd one out. Maybe they have their reasons, but they should be explicit https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/sql-delete.html

Comment: 8.2 is **not** the ["current" documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html). A syntax diagram only documents the available option. Therefor any option _not_ included in the syntax diagram is automatically not supported. The SQL standard does not include any option to "join" tables in a DELETE statement. So Postgres' `USING` option is just as non-standard as the `JOIN` option MySQL and SQL Server use. Neither of them defines the "standard" and e.g. Oracle and DB2 have not option at all to "join" other tables

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
DELETE from m_productprice
WHERE  m_pricelist_version_id='1000020'
       AND m_product_id IN (SELECT m_product_id
                            FROM   m_product
                            WHERE  upc = '7094');
```

Comment: Yes this is what postgres recommend as the 'standard' way to do it in the [delete documentation notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html#id-1.9.3.100.8): "A more standard way to do it is: `DELETE FROM films WHERE producer_id IN (SELECT id FROM producers WHERE name = 'foo');`". So the good thing of this is that this sql will work in other databases.

Answer (score 458):

```
DELETE 
FROM m_productprice B  
     USING m_product C 
WHERE B.m_product_id = C.m_product_id AND
      C.upc = '7094' AND                 
      B.m_pricelist_version_id='1000020';
```

or

```
DELETE 
FROM m_productprice
WHERE m_pricelist_version_id='1000020' AND 
      m_product_id IN (SELECT m_product_id 
                       FROM m_product 
                       WHERE upc = '7094');
```

Comment: @0mesh its for mysql .. my doubt is for sql and postgre sql

Comment: for larger tables, the first solution in this answer is potentially much faster.

Comment: The best answer, especially the first one, as it allows you to match by multiple fields.

Comment: the second one will work across all databases

Comment: What if you don't have a key column to use due to some temporary factor? If I know the rows I want to delete, from the result of a query, but don't necessarily have some specific identifier for them, how?

Comment: What I don't love about the first option is that it's harder to swap the `DELETE` with a `SELECT *` to test which records you're about to delete before actually executing the delete query.

Answer (score 82):

If you have more than one join you could use comma separated USING statements:

```
DELETE 
FROM 
      AAA AS a 
USING 
      BBB AS b,
      CCC AS c
WHERE 
      a.id = b.id 
  AND a.id = c.id
  AND a.uid = 12345 
  AND c.gid = 's434sd4'
```

[Reference](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/guidelines-for-sql/writing-code-compliant-with-both-mysql-and-postgresql/mysqlism-and-0)

Comment: The `a.id = b.id` part is basically the join.  I overlooked this, but it's the key piece, thank you!

Answer (score 55):

Another form that works with Postgres 9.1+ is combining a Common Table Expression with the USING statement for the join.

```
WITH prod AS (select m_product_id, upc from m_product where upc='7094')
DELETE FROM m_productprice B
USING prod C
WHERE B.m_product_id = C.m_product_id 
AND B.m_pricelist_version_id = '1000020';
```

Comment: CTEs maybe 9.1+ but `USING` was allowed in 8.2 as well https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/sql-delete.html

Answer (score 32):

Just use a subquery with INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN or smth else:

```
DELETE FROM m_productprice
WHERE m_product_id IN
(
  SELECT B.m_product_id
  FROM   m_productprice  B
    INNER JOIN m_product C 
    ON   B.m_product_id = C.m_product_id
  WHERE  C.upc = '7094' 
  AND    B.m_pricelist_version_id = '1000020'
)
```

to optimize the query,

- use [NOT EXISTS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-subquery.html) instead of `IN`
- and [WITH](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/queries-with.html) for large subqueries

Answer (score 9):

Essentially everything mentioned here is mentioned in the docs, but no-one is specifying exactly what. So this is what the *current (v15)* [`DELETE` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-delete.html#id-1.9.3.100.8) says:

> #### Notes
>
> PostgreSQL lets you reference columns of other tables in the `WHERE` condition by specifying the other tables in the `USING` clause. For example, to delete all films produced by a given producer, one can do:
>
> ```sql
> DELETE FROM films USING producers
>  WHERE producer_id = producers.id AND producers.name = 'foo';
> ```
>
> What is essentially happening here is a join between films and producers, with all successfully joined films rows being marked for deletion. This syntax is not standard. A more standard way to do it is:
>
> ```sql
> DELETE FROM films
>  WHERE producer_id IN (SELECT id FROM producers WHERE name = 'foo');
> ```
>
> In some cases the join style is easier to write or faster to execute than the sub-select style.

Answer (score 0):

By use of using , we can do that.

```
****

DELETE B.* FROM m_productprice B using m_product C where B.m_product_id = C.m_product_id and C.upc = '7094' AND B.m_pricelist_version_id = '1000020'
------------------------------------------------------------------------

****
```