# delete record from select by composite key

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I've been able to come up with a query that selects those records that I want to delete, but now I am stuck at being able to convert this to a delete query. The problem is that a composite key describes the selected rows, so a normal `delete from table where key in (select key...)` won't work (at least not for Postgres).

Is there any way of getting this to work?

This is the select query:

```
SELECT t1.*, link.*, t2.* FROM tbl as t1
JOIN link on link.a = t1.link_id
JOIN tbl as t2
ON link.b = t2.link_id
WHERE t1.data = t2.data and 
t1.some_id = q2.some_id
```

`tbl` can be identified by `some_id` and `link_id` (and potentially a 3rd identifier in some cases which I didn't mention).

Comment: This is not a pretty way to do it, but couldn't you concatenate the keys and the query results?  E.g. `delete from table where key1 || key2 || key3 in (select t1.key1 || t2.key2 || t3.key3 from t1, t2, t3 where...)` (`||` is how you concatenate in Oracle; not sure what it is in Postgres)

Comment: The keys are numeric, so concatenating them would potentially remove wrong ones (think about `key1=11` and `key2=1` - this could also mean `key1=1` and `key2 = 11` as the concatenated version is 111).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753904/postgresql-delete-with-inner-join has some really nice answers regarding deletion with joins and cte

Answer (score 3):

Ahh... I think I answered it (should have thought longer about it).

```
DELETE FROM tbl as t1 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM link
  JOIN tbl as t2
    ON link.b = t2.link_id
  WHERE 
      link.a = t1.link_id 
  AND t1.data = t2.data 
  AND t1.some_id = t2.some_id
)
```

Comment: where you get `q2.some_id`?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. The first SELECT FROM from the original select query is placed outside of the new select query and part of the DELETE now.

Comment: `EXISTS` is likely the best solution here. You could also use `DELETE ... USING ...`, or you could use `IN (...)` with a list of composite types.

Comment: I also think you miss the from in the inner select.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Does postgres support `IN(...)` for composite keys?

Comment: @orange `SELECT  ROW(1,2) IN ( ROW(1,2), ROW(3,4) );`