# Postgres - DELETE JOIN, USING giving error

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-delete

So it doesn't seem like there are `DELETE JOIN`s in Postgres so I tried using `USING`:

```
DELETE FROM
    creator.list_items li
USING
    creator.lists l
USING
    item_instances ii
WHERE
    li.list_id = l._id
    AND
    li.item_instance_id = ii._id
    AND
    ii.item_id IN ($1:list)
    AND
    l._id = $2
    AND
    l.account_id = $3
```

but it just gives me the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USING"
LINE 5:                 USING
```

my original query:

```
DELETE 
    li
FROM
    creator.list_items li
JOIN
    creator.lists l
    ON
        li.list_id = l._id
JOIN
    item_instances ii
    ON
        li.item_instance_id = ii._id
WHERE
    ii.item_id IN ($1:list)
    AND
    l._id = $2
    AND
    l.account_id = $3
```

Comment: The `using` keyword can only be used once, just like e.g. the `where` keyword.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL delete with inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753904/postgresql-delete-with-inner-join)

Comment: @Jens so I've got two `USING`s in my query, does that mean I just need to use more `SELECT` in the `WHERE` part?

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use `JOIN` in the `USING` clause:

```
DELETE FROM
    creator.list_items li
USING creator.lists l JOIN
      item_instances ii
      ON li.list_id = l._id
WHERE li.item_instance_id = ii._id AND
      ii.item_id IN ($1:list) AND
      l._id = $2 AND
      l.account_id = $3;
```

Comment: for that query I'm getting: `HINT:  There is an entry for table "li", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.` needed to switch `ii` and `li` to get rid of the error.

Comment: hold on, I messed up, that would just delete from `item_instances`, so the problem still stands

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i made an edit before which was incorrect, which I am referring to, you can check the edit history.

Answer (score 0):

My functioning query:

```
DELETE FROM
    creator.list_items li
USING 
    creator.lists l 
WHERE 
    li.item_instance_id 
        IN 
        (
            SELECT
                _id
            FROM
                creator.item_instances
            WHERE
                item_id IN ($1:list) 
        )
    AND
    li.list_id = $2 
    AND
    li.list_id = l._id
    AND
    l.account_id = $3
```